# How to take the first 13 coefficients in MFCC

Tags: c++, mfcc

I have a trouble with MFCC. I have followed the tutorial step by step. After step "Windowing", I compute DFT for every frames. My question is: Will the remaining steps, including "Mel-filter bank", "log" and "DCT", apply to every frames? I feel confused because in step "DCT", we will take the first 13 coefficients which was computed before. So what frames we have to take it? I really need a clear explanation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would like to suggest [this](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/) tutorial if you have not already seen it.

Yes, you have to apply DFT, Mel-filter bank, log and DCT to **EACH AND VERY FRAME** and then get the first 13 coefficients of DCT. The coefficients can be stored in an array of array of double (say vector< vector< double> > mfcc). Then each mfcc(i).size = 13 i.e. the first 13 coefficients of each frame.
Therefore each mfcc(i) will contain the 13 coefficients of each frame and mfcc will be a vector of these 13 coefficients.

I would suggest you to use a c++ librry for mfcc extraction instead of doing things from scratch.

Comment: I am reading this website :D. Could you give me your gmail? If I don't understand, I will ask you :D. Thanks :D!

Comment: Actually I'm also a beginner at this, and have started implementing speech recognition in C++ so I think I would also need some help. Here is email id - tushardobhal23@gmail.com

Comment: So coincidental :)). Okay, now I am not alone :)). My gmail is: tuanit96@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

MFCC is a purely local operation. It is done repeatedly on every frame: `for (auto f: frames) { std::vector<double> coeff = MFCC(f);`. That means every part of the MFCC is also done repeatedly.